# clone a page with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a list of items in jQuery mobile from an array, and paginating them. The page's header and footer are included by PHP via a wordpress function. Basically what I'm doing is calculating the number of pages I need to accommodate the elements in the array, then cloning the page element that number of times, and looping over them to add the elements to each. At the end of each page I'm putting previous and next buttons.

The problem is that the buttons do not change pages at all.

The page element looks like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="press-media-page">

    <?php get_template_part("loop", "header"); ?>

    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Press &amp; Media</h1>
    </div>

    <?php get_template_part("loop", "footer"); ?>

</div>
```

To create each page:

```
newPage = $("#press-media-page").clone().attr({
    "id": "press-media-page-" + pageNumber,
    "data-url": "press-media-page-" + pageNumber
}).page();
```

And then after adding the elements and buttons, to append it to the document:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.append(newPage);
```

After I've created the pages, I loop over them and trigger the create event:

```
$("#press-media-page").trigger("create");
for (var i = 1; i < pages; i++)
    $("#press-media-page-" + i).trigger("create");
```

The page appears in the right place in the document, and the buttons are linked to the right page ID, but alas they don't navigate.

What do I have to do to get this to work?

### Edit

This is how I create the buttons:

```
if (pageNumber > 0)
    navButtonGrid.left.append("<a>").attr({
        "href": "#press-media-page" + ((pageNumber > 1) ? "-" + (pageNumber - 1) : ""),
        "data-role": "button",
        "data-icon": "arrow-l",
        "data-iconpos": "left"
    }).text("View Newer");
if (pageNumber < totalPages - 1)
    navButtonGrid.right.append("<a>").attr({
        "href": "#press-media-page-" + (pageNumber + 1),
        "data-role": "button",
        "data-icon": "arrow-r",
        "data-iconpos": "right"
    }).text("View Older");
```

I haven't taken over any events from the buttons, just using jQuery mobile's default link hijacking

Comment: Can you post an example of your button code?

Comment: done, although I haven't hooked into any events, and the markup appears correct after it's enhanced

Comment: Try adding a $("#press-media-page-" + i).page() instead of $("#press-media-page-" + i).trigger("create");

Comment: Does your data-role="page" div have a data-url after it gets rendered?

Comment: @bmurmistro well I'm setting the data-url explicitly. Before it would just keep the data-url of the page I cloned it from

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7987/discussion-between-bmurmistro-and-carson-myers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it turned out to be a silly mistake:

```
navButtonGrid.left.append("<a>").attr({ //...
```

I append an `<a>` tag, but then I'm still working on the `navButtonGrid.left` element, which is a `ui-block` div. Changing it to

```
navButtonGrid.left.append($("<a>").attr({ /* ... */ }));
```

has solved the problem.